# How to include PDF file in LaTex Doc from folder location?

Tags: graphics, external-files, pdfpages

I'm using the `\usepackage{pdfpages}` to include PDF files.

I'm using the following convention: `\includepdf[pages={1-7}]{myFile.pdf}`

My question is, how can you include a link to a folder that contains the PDF?

I tried this with no luck: `\includepdf[pages={1-7}]{Resources/myFile.pdf}`

My folder "Resources" is in the same folder as my Tex doc and the error I get trying to find the location is this:

```
Missing $ inserted ../Resources/myFile.pdf}.
```

Comment: You can even use something like `\includepdf[pages={1-}]{\detokenize{/Users/my_name/Desktop/Folder1/Folder2/Name of folder with spaces or accents/ My_CV/ CV_LATEX/CV_Academic_English.pdf}}`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You either need to specify the full path e.g.:

```
\includepdf[pages={1-7}]{/home/bob/Documents/MyFolder/Resources/myfile.pdf}
```

or specify it relative to the current directory e.g. suppose your document is /home/jane/mydirectory/mydoc.tex and you need to include /home/jane/myotherdirectory/Resources/myfile.pdf then:

```
\includepdf[pages={1-7}]{../myotherdirectory/Resources/myfile.pdf}
```

If Resources is a sub-directory of your current directory, try:

```
\includepdf[pages={1-7}]{./Resources/myfile.pdf}
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error: `Missing $ inserted ../Resources/myFile.pdf}`. My folder "Resources" is in the same folder as my Tex doc.

Comment: This is why you need to provide a MWE - so that people have sufficient information about the problem you're trying to solve to not have to guess the details! Anyway, I've edited to accommodate this third possibility.

Comment: A MWE isn't applicable in this situation as you do not have the files or locations I'm testing, therefore is irrelevant. I provided enough details, including unsuccessful attempts. However if other questions arise, I shall bare that in mind. Your third option solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. I just realised that I somehow missed the information concerning the relative location of the pdf to be included when I first read your question. (That's why my initial attempt at an answer didn't address that location and why I said you didn't provide enough details.) Again, my apologies.

Comment: Cfr does not need to apologize as you are on a correct track.

Comment: No one needs to apologise. I appreciate your time and glad the answer got it working :D

Comment: For future reference: What solved this for me was that if Resources is a sub-directory of your current directory just use nothing instead of `./` (`./` did not work for me), resulting in: `\includepdf[pages={1-7}]{Resources/myfile.pdf}`. Perhaps this is the valid solution as of today, maybe depending on coding environment, package versions, packages...

Comment: @jibo That should work and is what I would usually use and recommend. However, this answer was to a question concerning a situation in which it was explicitly stated that the syntax you give failed. Hence, my suggested alternative.