# Include PDF pages in latex

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I am trying to include some pages from a PDF file in my appendices section on Latex.

I tried to follow : [How to include PDF file in LaTex Doc from folder location?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149443/how-to-include-pdf-file-in-latex-doc-from-folder-location)

But I am still getting errors.

I used

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

and I included the file path of my pdf but it cannot locate the file, is there a way around this problem?

```
\includepdf[pages={1}]{\detokenize{C:/Users/jas_s/OneDrive - um.edu.mt/University/Masters/1st Year/MPH5008 - Dissertation/Journals/8. IAEA series no.25.pdf}}
```

Comment: First, lose the detokenize.  If that doesn't work, create a shortcut (link) tin the current directory than doesn't use blanks, etc.

Comment: Doesn't `"..." ` work?

Comment: I tried to place my file in my desktop to have a shorter path but still same problem. `\includepdf[pages={1}]{C:\Users\jas_s\Desktop\IAEAfile.pdf}`

Comment: And to add to my comment I had also tried `\includepdf[pages={1}]{...\Desktop\IAEAfile.pdf}`, still does not locate the pdf file

Comment: LaTeX supports UNIX style pathnames.   IIRC, full pathnames start with "//" (as opposed to relative pathnames).

Comment: Could you provide an example please? the current path of my file is `C:\Users\jas_s\Desktop\IAEAfile.pdf`, I tried `C:\\Users\jas_s\Desktop\IAEAfile.pdf` but also did not work